# How can I show detail value of Recoil Extension on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, recoiljs

[image: recoil-err]

Here is my Recoil Extension, How can I see my state on this

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to be more specific and provide some contextual information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.